# Asp.net realizar una busqueda y poner la respuesta en un @html.labelFor

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto `asp.net`.

Quiero que al escoger un nombre de la `selectlist` me aparezca el id con el cual esta registrado. Podria ser en un `@html.labelFor`, un `@html.editFor` o un `@html.DisplayFor`  sin necesidad de darle click a un botón. Es decir, que sea dinámica

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo del controlador es el siguiente:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Compr_ingreso = new SelectList(db.ClaseComprobante, "Codigo", "Nombre");
    ViewBag.Compr_egreso = new SelectList(db.ClaseComprobante, "Codigo", "Nombre");
    ViewBag.Contr_banco = new SelectList(db.PlanCuentas, "CODIGO", "NOMBRE");
    ViewBag.Contr_otro = new SelectList(db.PlanCuentas, "CODIGO", "NOMBRE");
    ViewBag.Cta_efectivo = new SelectList(db.PlanCuentas, "CODIGO", "NOMBRE");
    ViewBag.Cta_cheque = new SelectList(db.PlanCuentas, "CODIGO", "NOMBRE");
    ViewBag.Codigo_caja = new SelectList(db.Caja, "Codigo_caja", "Nombre_caja");
    ViewBag.Nit_cajero = new SelectList(db.Terceros, "NIT", "NIT");
    return View();
}

// POST: configCajeroes/Create
// Para protegerse de ataques de publicación excesiva, habilite las propiedades específicas a las que desea enlazarse. Para obtener
// más información vea https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Codigo_caja,Nit_cajero,Compr_ingreso,Compr_egreso,Contr_banco,Contr_otro,Cta_efectivo,Cta_cheque")] configCajero configCajero)
{
    if (db.configCajero.Any(a => a.Nit_cajero == configCajero.Nit_cajero))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Nit_cajero", "Usuario ya se encuentra asignado a una caja");
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.configCajero.Add(configCajero);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.Compr_ingreso = new SelectList(db.ClaseComprobante, "Codigo", "Nombre", configCajero.Compr_ingreso);
    ViewBag.Compr_egreso = new SelectList(db.ClaseComprobante, "Codigo", "Nombre", configCajero.Compr_egreso);
    ViewBag.Contr_banco = new SelectList(db.PlanCuentas, "CODIGO", "NOMBRE", configCajero.Contr_banco);
    ViewBag.Contr_otro = new SelectList(db.PlanCuentas, "CODIGO", "NOMBRE", configCajero.Contr_otro);
    ViewBag.Cta_efectivo = new SelectList(db.PlanCuentas, "CODIGO", "NOMBRE", configCajero.Cta_efectivo);
    ViewBag.Cta_cheque = new SelectList(db.PlanCuentas, "CODIGO", "NOMBRE", configCajero.Cta_cheque);
    ViewBag.Codigo_caja = new SelectList(db.Caja, "Codigo_caja", "Nombre_caja", configCajero.Codigo_caja);
    ViewBag.Nit_cajero = new SelectList(db.Terceros, "NIT", "NIT", configCajero.Nit_cajero);
    return View(configCajero);
}
```

Y el de la vista en `cshtml` es el siguiente:

```
@model OperativaCaja.Models.configCajero

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Configurar cajero";
}

<h2>Asignar Usuario a Caja</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4></h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>Codigo de Caja</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.DropDownList("Codigo_caja", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Codigo_caja, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 ">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nit_cajero, "aqui poner el dato de la busqueda ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>NIT de Cajero</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.DropDownList("Nit_cajero", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nit_cajero, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 ">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nit_cajero, "pendiente", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>Comprobante Ingreso</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.DropDownList("Compr_ingreso", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Compr_ingreso, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 ">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nit_cajero, "pendiente", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>Comprobante Egreso</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.DropDownList("Compr_egreso", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Compr_egreso, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 ">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nit_cajero, "pendiente", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12 ">
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <label style="display:inline-block; text-align:center; color:#0026ff">Comprobantes Contables para Contrapartidas</label>
                <br /><br />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>Contrapartida Banco</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.DropDownList("Contr_banco", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contr_banco, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 ">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nit_cajero, "pendiente", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>Contrapartida Otro</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.DropDownList("Contr_otro", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contr_otro, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 ">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nit_cajero, "pendiente", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12 ">
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <label style="display:inline-block; text-align:center; color:#0026ff">Cuentas Contables para Operativa de Caja</label>
                <br /><br />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>Cuenta Efectivo</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.DropDownList("Cta_efectivo", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cta_efectivo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 ">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nit_cajero, "pendiente", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>Cuenta Cheque</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.DropDownList("Cta_cheque", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cta_cheque, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 ">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nit_cajero, "pendiente", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues en tu controlador necesitas agregar el metodo:

```
[HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetCajeroInfo(int cajeroId)

        {
           var cajeroInfo= dataLayer.GetCajeroInfo(cajeroId);
            var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, cajeroInfo);
            return response;
        }
```

Esto es para hacer un background request mediante javascript o alguna libreria como jquery

en la declaracion de tu control DropDown agregas el llamado a una funcion javascript para cuando se cambie el cajeroId:

@Html.CustomDropDownListFor(model => model.Nit_cajero, null, new { onchange = "getCajeroPorId()" })

declaracion de tu funcion script (jquery) en la pagina:

```
<script>  
    function getCajeroPorId()  
{  
        debugger;  
        var cajeroId= $("#Nit_cajero").val();  
        $.ajax  
        ({  
            url: '/TuControladorDeDatos/GetCajeroInfo',  
            type: 'POST',  
            datatype: 'application/json',  
            contentType: 'application/json',  
            data: JSON.stringify({  
                cajeroId: +cajeroId  
            }),  
            success: function(result)  
          {  
                //aqui actualizas tus labels y demas controladores con la info recibida
            },  
            error: function()  
            {  
                alert(" uups revisar error.")  
            },  
        });  
    }  
</script>
```

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias amigo Funciono a la prfeccion